# What formula would I use to relate velocity to rotation I Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm messing around in Unity trying to create a script for a physics based arrow.
I have it arcing properly, but it's still straight up throughout it's flight.
I'm trying to use `Quaternion.LookRotation` to change it's rotation based on the velocity `(R = 0 at V = Vinitial, R = 90 at V = 0, and R = 180 at V = -Vinitial)` but I haven't been able to puzzle out what formula I would use.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

With help from the responses, I was able to get it working as I intended. Incase anyone stumbles across this looking for help, my end code looked like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (ForceSet)
    {
        ForceSet = false;
        initialVelocity = rb.velocity;
        EndAngleOffset = .33f * rb.velocity.y;
    }
    if (stuckTarget == null)
    {
        Vector3 Forward;
        Vector3 Upward;
        if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
        {
            Forward = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, -((-initialVelocity.y + rb.velocity.y - EndAngleOffset) * (-initialVelocity.y + rb.velocity.y - EndAngleOffset)), rb.velocity.z);
            Upward = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Forward = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, ((initialVelocity.y + rb.velocity.y + EndAngleOffset) * (initialVelocity.y + rb.velocity.y + EndAngleOffset)), rb.velocity.z);
            Upward = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
        }
        rb.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Forward, Upward);
```

}

(ForceSet is set equal to true the when applying the launching force to the 'Arrow')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the arrows `Rigidbody` component, you can access it's `velocity` property and set its `rotation` to be equal to its `velocity`.

I recommend when making modifications to a `Rigidbody`'s transform that you use the `Rigidbody` methods. This ensures that values are properly updated with Unity's physics system.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rigidbody.velocity, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Depending on the circumstances, you might want to change `Update` to `FixedUpdate`.

**EDIT:**

There was a **bug in the above code** I fixed; that's what you get when you write it at 2am. I'd give it another go and see if that works for you.

In an ideal world, you would pre-compute the path of the arrow so that you could perform any procedural animation to the arrow you would like.

You could also calculate an X rotation to use instead, which will fake the effect.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float lookMagnitude = 45.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float velocitySensitivity;

    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Determine how much we want to fake the rotation by.
        var lookStrength = Mathf.InverseLerp(-velocitySensitivity, velocitySensitivity, rigidbody.velocity)

        var targetEulerAngles = new Vector3(
         Mathf.Lerp(-lookMagnitude, lookMagnitude, lookStrength),
         transform.localEulerAngles.y,
         transform.localEulerAngles.z
        );

        // Rotate the transform
        transform.localEulerAngles = targetEulerAngles;

        // Alternatively, interpolate to the target angle.
        /* transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(
         *  transform.localEulerAngles,
         *  targetEulerAngles,
         *  Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed
         * );
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've given me a good start, though I still have some work to do on it. It only rotates between rough 45 and 90 degrees right now, and I'm trying to get it to go from 45 to -45 (as it starts and lands, respectively), if you might have advice on that.

Comment: I've made an edit to try and give more flexibility, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine just getting the transform rotation and setting it equal to `Quaternion.LookRotation(velocity)`